# Java/ Talend Breaking down a String based on a condition and cleaning data

Tags: java, talend

I have a list of strings of raw data. Each string may contain Name of company + Stress Address + city+ Province in Talend 7. They are separated by a pipe in the string.

The total number of rows is 200,000.

I want to extract and separate the company name in an efficient way. The Problem is the pipe exists irregularly for the name of the company.

Here are some examples each string can have:

1. "Mackenzie Health|10 Trench St.|Richmond Hill ON  L4C 4Z3"
2. ""
3. "Health and Wellness Center|University of Toronto|214 College Street, Room 111|Toronto ON  M5T 2Z9"
4. "400 Walmer Road|Suite 125|Toronto ON  M5P 2X7"
5. "The Hospital for Sick Children|Dept. of Critical Care Medicine|2nd Floor Atrium, Room 2830|555 University Ave|Toronto ON  M5G 1X8"

I am thinking of using a tJava or tJavaRow, and writing some java code, using the contains method I can check if a string contains one of these words: Avenue, Ave, Road, Rd, Street and, St. except if there is room before these words.

Here is my problem: After finding which record has a street address I need to know if there is any pipe exist before the street address and if yes how many? So I can merge them as the company name.

Examples:

"Mackenzie Health|10 Trench St.|Richmond Hill ON  L4C 4Z3" there is only one pipe before the street address 10 Trench St. so the company name is 
Mackenzie Health

"Health and Wellness Center|University of Toronto|214 College Street, Room 111|Toronto ON  M5T 2Z9" there are two pipes before the street address, so the name of the company is:
Health and Wellness Center University of Toronto

"400 Walmer Road|Suite 125|Toronto ON  M5P 2X7" there is no pipe before it so there is not any name

"The Hospital for Sick Children|Dept. of Critical Care Medicine|2nd Floor Atrium, Room 2830|555 University Ave|Toronto ON  M5G 1X8" There are three pipes before it but in the substring, before it, there is the word room. So the name of the company is The Hospital for Sick Children Dept. of Critical Care Medicine.

Appreciate any idea and/or new solution also

Comment: It is a pipe (|) separated string, split each string with pipe and form an object model/bean and populate the data.

Comment: @Sambit could you explain more? note that I am using Talend so I need to write as simple as possible code in a tJavarow, for example.

Comment: For example, if this is the string "Mackenzie Health|10 Trench St.|Richmond Hill ON L4C 4Z3", you have split it using pipe (|) and create a class which has some fields for your requirements. The class should have getter and setter. After splitting, populate the data to your class.

Comment: That is the problem, Talend is very restricted does not allow you to create a class inside a Talend component. The solution that I usually use is I add a new field in a tMap and count the pipes generally the I separate them by a tFilter. I cannot use this soluton here as now I have a special condition and the number of rows are high

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Java method, in a Talend routine, based on pattern matching using capturing groups (can be called in tMap componant, or elsewhere).

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_capturing_groups.htm

In your case, you can use the following example of RegEx (seems to resolve the 5 examples given):

This Regex groups by the last occurrence (from right):

```
^(.*\|)*((?i).*(room|st.|street|road|avenue).*\|(?-i).*)$
```

I have tested the RegEx by means of https://regex101.com/. Group 1 is your compagny name, Group 2 is your address. You can delete the undesired pipes in a further treatment.

This Regex groups by the first occurrence (from left):

```
^((((?!room|street|st.|road|avenue).)*\|)|)*((?i).*(room|street|st.|road|avenue).*\|(?-i).*)$.
```

Group 2 and Group 4 now have the data.

**Note:** All credits are for Mo2s, I just copied his answer from the comment to here, hoping it will be useful for others.

**FIXED:** problem in RegEx with star character, confusion with stackoverflow tags.

Hope that it can be usefull to you. Say me if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you @Mo2s I have two questions: 1- to make sure that I understand correctly this  (.\|)((?i). means I have strings with 0 or pipeline and be group 1, and the rest is group 2. 2-  if I want to add Ave and Rd I should add them here room|st.|street|road|avenue|Ave|Rd ?

Comment: G. Hak. 1. I have edited my answer. The RegEx was wrong because it has been modified by stackoverflow editor (confusion with tags). 2. "If I want to add Ave and Rd I should add them here room|st.|street|road|avenue|Ave|Rd" -> Yes.

Comment: What happens if there are two of the words in the string? for example, Health and Wellness Center|University of Toronto|214 College Street| 2N Street|Toronto ON M5T 2Z?

Comment: Same behavior, groups remain the sames. I encourage you to test the regular expression with your examples on https://regex101.com/. Note that the RegEx given may have to be improve, depending of your other cases/situations.

Comment: I tested with regex101.com.  if there is more than one match. It groups from the right or last one. I tried to improve that to group the string from left. But it wasn't successful.

Comment: Hi G. Hak.. Thanks for your comment. Give me an example and the result which you are expected. I will try.

Comment: Hi @Mo2s here are two samples:
First string "Sleep & Alertness Clinic|790 Bay street | 32 st.|Suite 800||Toronto ON  M5G 1N8"
The result I want is "Sleep & Alertness Clinic|" in the first group and "790 Bay street | 32 st.|Suite 800||Toronto ON  M5G 1N8" in the second group, the pipe's place after "Sleep & Alertness Clinic doesn't matter

Second string: "Royal Health Care| Centre|130 Adelaide St. West|  92 Avenue|Toronto ON  M5H 3P5"
The result should be:
Group 1: Royal Health Care| Centre
Group 2: 130 Adelaide St. West|  92 Avenue|Toronto ON  M5H 3P5

Comment: Hi G. Hak.. Try the following RegEx: ^((((?!room|street|st.|road|avenue).)*\|)|)*((?i).*(room|street|st.|road|avenue).*\|(?-i).*)$. Groups to catch are now 2 and 4. Keep me informed. Thanks.

Comment: it seems that it works thank you. I put it to your answer above. One last question I used it in a tReplace but it didn't work. For a simple Regex, we put $s1 or $s2  in Replace (advanced Setting)to get the part we need but it seems as it is a group these commands are not working, do you know what should I put or tReplace does not work with grouping?

Comment: Thanks G. Hak.. If you use the RegEx proposed in Java code, you have to use "\\" (double) instead of "\" (single). However, I sugest to you to use a Java method (written in a routine) using pattern matching. Maybe you can also use tExtractRegexFields componant (?).